# Can someone here explain to me how the third line in this code works with a two character substring?

Tags: python, indexing, substring

For example, in the string "chilchil", the substring is 'ch' and according to the index variable, the index of 'ch' in the first occurrence is 0, and in the second occurrence 2 (0+2), but actually the second occurrence is at 4, not at 2. I would appreciate an explanation. here is the code

```
string = input("Please type in a string: ")
substring = input("Please type in a substring: ")
index = string.find(substring, string.find(substring)+len(substring))
if index != -1:
    print(f"The second occurrence of the substring is at index {index}")
else:
    print("The substring doesn't occur twice in the string")
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the code outputs 2, but you expected that it should output 4?

Comment: "and in the second occurrence 2 " why do you think the second occurrence is at index 2?

Comment: It outputs 4 as I expected, but according to the line of code it should output 2, am I wrong?

Comment: ~I'm not sure what's wrong on your side but for those inputs I get 4 on bith python2 and python3~ oh ... you wanted it the other way around ...

Comment: _in the second occurrence 2 (0+2)_ No, it is not 2.  It is 4.  You must have made some mistake. Voting to close.

Comment: string.find(substring) + len(substring): calculates the index immediately after the end of the first occurrence, which is 0 + 2 = 2.  I'm new to programming, maybe I'm missing something

Comment: By the way, this would have been a better question if you had used the hardcoded strings `"chilchil"` and `"ch"`  instead of using `input()`.  And doing so probably would have revealed whatever mistake you made, so you would not have even needed to ask the question!

Comment: _calculates the index immediately after the end of the first occurrence_ No it does not.  The index is still calculated **from the start of the string**.

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter to [str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), `start`, doesn't affect the string being searched, it only affects where the search begins. The returned index is still relative to the start of the original string.

Break it down:

```
string = 'chilchil'
substring = 'ch'

first_idx = string.find(substring)  # first_idx = 0
first_len = len(substring)          # first_len = 2
start = first_idx + first_len       # start = 2

index = string.find(substring, start)  # start search at index 2
# index = 4
```

You can also look up help documentation in the REPL:

```
>>> help(str.find)
Help on method_descriptor:


find(...)
    S.find(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int
    
    Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
    arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.
    
    Return -1 on failure.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seen the previous comments I think you wanted something like this

```
>>> x="chilchil"
>>> y="ch"
>>> x[x.find(y)+len(y):].find(y)
2
```

but without the proper context I can't see the real use-case/benefit for doing something like this.
I still hope it helps you.

Comment: hmm from what I understand I think this is what they expected the `.find` to return, but they want 4, they just don't udnerstand how `4` is being returned from `.find`

Comment: oh, yeah ... it might also be that ... not a matter of "how to get this answer" but "why I get this answer". In that case I agree with you reading the `help()` is best advice one could give